# Where does the tests are running when I use AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a rails application, I am using AWS CodeBuild for the CI/CD process.
One of my test is failing randomly, how can I debug that? What's the environment that contains my build process?

Comment: Every CB build has detailed logs. Did you check them?

Answer (score 0):

Does rails support any of the [listed formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/test-reporting.html)?

If so, you need to export them as `reports` [in your buildspec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.reports).